# Erro executar UPDATE SQL Server

Tags: query, sql-update, sql-server-2012

Ao executar a instrução update abaixo está ocorrendo o seguinte erro. O que pode ser?

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Somente uma expressão pode ser especificada na lista de seleção quando a subconsulta não é introduzida com EXISTS

```
UPDATE EstoqueTarefa 
SET EstTarTitulo = (SELECT CONCAT(EstTarTitulo, '-' ,DATENAME(MONTH,getdate())),'-',DATEPART(YEAR,getdate())) 
where EstTarID = 246
```

Comment: Você quer concatenar `EstTarTitulo + - + Mês + - + Ano`? Acho que tem um parêntese a mais depois do `getdate()`, que deveria estar no final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na SubQuery, apenas realiza select campo1, campo2, etc. Você não precisa de usar o Select porque a função GETDATE() pode ser invocada sem problema.

```
SET EstTarTitulo = CONCAT(EstTarTitulo, '-' ,DATENAME(MONTH,getdate()),'-',DATEPART(YEAR,getdate()))
```

Comment: Deu tudo @Claudio Lopes, obrigado.